# Tensorflow: Memory growth cannot differ between GPU devices | How to use multi-GPU with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, tf.keras, multi-gpu

I am trying to run a keras code on a GPU node within a cluster. The GPU node has 4 GPUs per node. I made sure to have all 4 GPUs within the GPU node available for my use. I run the code below to let tensorflow use the GPU:

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
    try:
        for gpu in gpus:
            tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
            logical_gpus = tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU')
            print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
    except RuntimeError as e:
        print(e)
```

The 4 GPUs available get listed in the output. However, I got the following error when running the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/BayesOptimization.py", line 20, in <module>
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
  File "/.conda/envs/thesis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/config.py", line 439, in list_logical_devices
    return context.context().list_logical_devices(device_type=device_type)
  File "/.conda/envs/thesis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py", line 1368, in list_logical_devices
    self.ensure_initialized()
  File "/.conda/envs/thesis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py", line 511, in ensure_initialized
    config_str = self.config.SerializeToString()
  File "/.conda/envs/thesis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py", line 1015, in config
    gpu_options = self._compute_gpu_options()
  File "/.conda/envs/thesis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py", line 1074, in _compute_gpu_options
    raise ValueError("Memory growth cannot differ between GPU devices")
ValueError: Memory growth cannot differ between GPU devices
```

Shouldn't the code list all the available gpus and set memory growth to true for each one?

I am currently using tensorflow libraries and python 3.97:

```
tensorflow                2.4.1           gpu_py39h8236f22_0
tensorflow-base           2.4.1           gpu_py39h29c2da4_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.4.1              pyheb71bc4_0
tensorflow-gpu            2.4.1                h30adc30_0
```

Any idea what the problem is and how to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! Can you replace  tf.config.set_memory_growth(gpu, True) with  tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True) and let us know?

Comment: Hi! I have done that already and got the same error.

Comment: Can you check the changes in this gist ? https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/mohantym/ac018207e02ddb995818a74667161e0b/stack_71319195.ipynb.  You can also set a range like [1:] /[2:] to use specific Gpu cards.

Comment: The code ran after I deleted the following two lines:
            **logical_gpus = tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU')
            print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")**

Not sure if that solves the problem, the set_memory_growth code works fine, but when the other line is called it throws the error.

Answer (score 2):

Try only: os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
instead of tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth.
This works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In case of multi-GPU devices memory growth should be constant through out all available GPUs. Either set it true for all GPUs or keep it false.

```
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
    for gpu in gpus:
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    logical_gpus = tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```

[Tensorflow GPU documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth)